# Автоматическая ширина родительского div в мобильных браузерах при использовании vh и vw?

Tags: css3, html, mobile-web

Вот например во всех обычных браузерах, выводится правильно-горизонтально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в мобильных ширина родительского div автоматически не вычисляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если указать размер вложенных div не в vh-vw , а в пикселях или em, то в мобильных браузерах правильно располагает элементы.

Ссылка на код.
http://jsfiddle.net/gnddx0ta/

```css
.container {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  border:3px solid red;
}

.firstMenuButtons {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.menuInfo {
  background-image: url(http://nic.ru/images/logo.gif);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menuIconButton {
  width: 7vw;
  height: 7vw;

  /* В пикселях правильно срабатывает
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  */

  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="firstMenuButtons">
    <div  class="menuIconButton menuInfo"></div>
    <div  class="menuIconButton menuInfo"></div>
    <div  class="menuIconButton menuInfo"></div>
    <div  class="menuIconButton menuInfo"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Как тогда поступать отказаться от vh и vw совсем? И что использовать, em?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохенько они [поддерживаются.](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)
В качестве альтернативы можно использовать jQuery, включая скрипт только для мобильных браузеров, например.

Для примера аналогом `100vh` будет следующий код (всё остальное можно вычислять как кратное этому):

```
function setHeight() {
    $('_block_').css({
        height: $(window).height() + 'px'
    });
}
```